# How to transform Promise<Document[]> in JS / TS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have the result of a long lasting operation, a MongoDB query:

> const a = collection.find({}).project({ name: 1 }).toArray()

It has the type of Promise<Document[]>

I would do a transformation, but it is not possible:

> let a2 = a.map((i) => {i._id, { name: i.name }})

In Vapor / Swift, there is a `map` not only for array, but also for promises, what about in JS / TS?

How can I apply further operation on the `Promise<Document[]>`?

Comment: Just use `await`?

Comment: Use `.then` for `map`ping over the promise.

Answer (score 0):

For Promises, you need to use .then for functionality and .catch for errors.

For example(reference):-

```
const promise = new Promise((resolved, rejected) => {
setTimeout(() =>{
console.log(rejected)
},1000)
})
promise.then((value) => console.log(value)).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

And always remember to write `return` when you are using a map and using {} because otherwise, you will get errors then.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the .then() function on different parts of the code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).